# Upload files with FlightPhp micro-framework

Tags: php, file, upload, flightphp

I already search this question on internet and on this forum, but I don't see any answers for this.

The question is **How to upload files with flightphp micro-framework with DropZonejs or others**.

**I have some code:**

```
DropZone:
<form action="/admin/upload" method="put" class="dropzone">
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="id" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
```

```
PHP:
function upload() {
    $uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/tmp/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . '1.jpg';
    //move_uploaded_file(json_encode(Flight::request()->getBody()), $uploadfile);
    echo json_encode(file_put_contents($uploadfile, Flight::request()->getBody()));
}
Flight::route('POST /admin/upload', 'upload');
```

I used too this example, but have error with '$_FILES['userfile']':

```
function upload_admin() {
        if(preg_match("/(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|GIF|JPG|JPEG|PNG)$/", $_FILES['userfile']['name']))
        {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
                echo "OK";
            }
        } 
    }

Flight::route('/admin/upload', 'upload_admin');
```

After execute all of this operations I have the `null` result.

For example, I drag some file to DropZone. DZ request /admin/upload/. It's works, but in the end I have 1.jpg with `null` size.
[Result of the uploading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7I2I.png)

Thanks to all.

UPD:Hmm, maybe it's problem in dropzonejs? I try some uploading php script without flightphp, and it doesn't upload files too with dropzone.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the files with getBody() method in Flight Framework. You can do it like

```
Flight::route('POST /admin/upload', function(){
    $request = Flight::request();
    $file = $request->files['id']; // (id) which is your html element name
});
```

**$file** variable contains some properties as you know, when you **var_dump()** it.

```
array(5) {
["name"]=>
string(14) "test_image.jpg"
["type"]=>
string(10) "image/jpeg"
["tmp_name"]=>
string(14) "/tmp/php6cpnDa"
["error"]=>
int(0)
["size"]=>
int(18101)
}
```